# No arroja datos en mi case 3 del tipo de triangulo y los resultados de area y perimetro en C ¿Que me faltaria?

Tags: c, switch

***Es un programa que calcula figuras pero en la opcion del triangulo no me aparece los resultados finales de area y perimetro.
Es para un proyecto escolar pero no sale los ultimos datos y tambien en la elipse no salen los resultados finales
que me podria faltar en el codigo?
// Esta es la parte que me falla al arrojar resultados no arroja nada
case 3: {

```
    printf("Elegiste el triangulo."); 
    printf("Digita el lado 1: ");
        scanf("%f",&a);
        setbuf ( stdin, NULL );
    printf("Digita el lado 2: ");
        scanf("%f",&c);
        setbuf ( stdin, NULL );
    printf("Digita la base: ");
        scanf("%f",&b);
        setbuf ( stdin, NULL );
    printf("Digita la altura: ");
    scanf("%f",altura); 
    setbuf ( stdin, NULL );
    if( a == b && a == c ){
        area = a + c + b ; 
    printf("Es un triangulo equilatero"); 
    printf("Su area es: %f",area); 
    printf("Su perimetro es: %f ",perimetro); 
    
    }
    else if(a  == c   && a !=b){
         area = (a +c) +  b;
         perimetro = ((b * altura)/2); 
        printf("Es un triangulo isoceles."); 
        printf("Su area es: %f",area); 
        printf("Su perimetro es: %f ",perimetro);
    
    }
    else if (a!=b&&a!=b&&b!=c ){
        area = a + c + b ; 
        perimetro = ((b * altura)/2);
        printf("Es un triangulo escaleno."); 
        printf("Su area es: %f",area); 
        printf("Su perimetro es: %f ",perimetro);
    }
    break; 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es el fin del codigo

Comment: Las capturas pueden ser útiles para detectar el problema, sin embargo, no debes poner capturas para mostrar código, sugiero que leas [sintaxis de markdown](https://markdown.es/sintaxis-markdown/)

Comment: Tienes un error de concepto grave, la variable que pones que se llama área calcula el perímetro y la que se llama perímetro calcula el area

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esncontre el error:

Cuando utilizas scanf para obtener la altura:

```
    printf("Digita la altura: ");
    scanf("%f",altura);
```

No pusiste el puntero "&" antes de la variable altura y eso es lo que te salta el error